# hive creates only 2 columns

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to create a table in hive, it creates only 2 columns instead of 3. I am using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1 int, col2 string, col3 int)
```

In addition, If I make the first column (in my input) a string, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot convert column 1 to integerjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string
```

Comment: I am using hive default database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal. When you create your table you define the first column as an Interger (with "int" properties). And apparently you are trying to insert a string in the first column. So of course if you want to insert a string you get an error.